# Extracting string data from a html view in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to grab both JS and CSS files that are inside a html mustache view.

Snippet of the view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>This is my beautiful page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="{{template_assets}}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{template_assets}}css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="{{template_assets}}css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="{{template_assets}}js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello world <a href="http://thisshouldnotbeincluded.com">test</a> <img src="neitherthis.jpg">
  </body>
</html>
```

Now the above content is inside a variable $file_get, by doing:

```
$file_scan = file_get_contents($view);
```

From here I would like to store css paths and js paths into each independent array so the final result would be:

```
$css_files = 
array (size=3)
  0 => string '{{template_assets}}css/bootstrap.css' (length=36)
  1 => string '{{template_assets}}css/style.css' (length=32)
  2 => string '{{template_assets}}css/bootstrap-responsive.css' (length=47)

$js_files = 
array (size=1)
  0 => string '{{template_assets}}js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js' (length=41)
```

How would I go through the file to grab the css and js files only? Should i loop through each line, but how (if

I have tried with str_replace and explode but with no luck

Thanks

Comment: Use `xpath` or `SimpleXML` or  `DOMDocument` to get all `<link src` and `<script src` values. Besides that, why don't you make the template files PHP files and simply use variables or methods in the view?

Comment: @DanFromGermany could you provide an example of how? To answer your other question, the purpose of this function i'm trying to get together is just for gathering js and css files from templates (that are in mustache format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` which is the correct way of doing this:

```
<?php
    $file_scan = file_get_contents($view);

    $css_files = array();
    $js_files = array();

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($file_scan);

    $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

    $links = $xpath->query('/html/head/link[@rel = "stylesheet"]');
    foreach ($links as $link) {
        $css_files[] = $link->getAttribute('href');
    }

    $scripts = $xpath->query('/html/head/script[@src]');
    foreach ($scripts as $script) {
        $js_files[] = $script->getAttribute('src');
    }

    var_dump($css_files);
    var_dump($js_files);
?>
```

If you feel you must use regular expressions, this will do it but it is more fragile than the `DOMDocument` approach:

```
<?php
    $file_scan = file_get_contents($view);

    $css_files = array();
    $js_files = array();

    if (preg_match_all('/"({{.*(?:.css|.js))"/', $file_scan, $matches) > 0) {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
            if (substr($match, -3) === 'css') {
                $css_files[] = $match;
            } else {
                $js_files[] = $match;
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($css_files);
    var_dump($js_files);
?>
```

Comment: If I put something like `My file might look like "test.css" see..` in the content, wouldn't this match too? Shouldn't be using regex/pregs, should use DOM classes. If you put `<script src=test.js>` which is invalid HTML but may appear too, it doesn't match.

Comment: Dan, I tried "test.css" with the above - doesnt match, so it works

Comment: @DanFromGermany: It will only match `.css` or `.js` after encountering `{{`.  It's not ideal, no.

Answer (score 1):

Using DOMDocument:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($file_scan);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$scripts = $dom->getElementsByTagName('script');
foreach ($scripts as $script) {
  echo $script->getAttribute('src');
}

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('link');
foreach ($links as $link) {
  if ($link->getAttribute('rel') == 'stylesheet') {
    echo $link->getAttribute('href');
  }
}
```

Comment: You need the `href` attribute from `link`, not the `src` attribute.

Comment: Corrected ;) Your XPath solution is the best anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Another regex solution, bit more flexible:

```
$rx_tpl = '/<%s\s+[^<>]*%s\s*=\s*"(\{\{[^"{}]+\}\}[^"{}]+)"/is';
$a_types = array(
    'css' => array('link', 'href'),
    'js' => array('script', 'src')
);
$a_results_by_type = array();
foreach ($a_types as $key => $a) {
    $a_curr = array();
    if (preg_match_all(sprintf($rx_tpl, $a[0], $a[1]), $file_scan, $a_matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER))
        $a_results_by_type[$key] = $a_matches[1];
}

print_r($a_results_by_type);
```